# Overlap the main div with the border

Tags: css, react-native

Basically, i had two buttons that had a top and bottom border, they are inside a view, like this

```
<View>
   <MyTab>Sobre</MyTab>
   <MyTab>Portfólio</MyTab>
</View>
```

[image: If you open the image on another tab you can see the current result]
This view is inside another one. This main container applies a padding arround the entire app. How can i make this border bottom and top to overlap this main padding and make the border to touch the end of the screen

My css applied to the buttons are

```
    navigationTabs: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.main.REGULAR,
        width: '50%', 
        borderRadius: 0,
        paddingTop: ScreenSize.getSpaces(10),
        paddingBottom: ScreenSize.getSpaces(10),
        marginBottom: ScreenSize.getSpaces(10),
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderColor: Colors.TEXT_DARK,
        borderTopWidth: 0.5,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    },
```

Comment: Did you try giving the child negative padding?

Comment: Actually broke my app when i apply a negative padding. Dont ask why

Comment: @AltairTodescattoF why?

Comment: Who knows. Just close the app when i save

Comment: Apply main container style = {flex:1} or you could draw border top and bottom outside of the navigationTab

Comment: The negative padding and marging works with a different aproach. I create a new class just to adjust the position and the size of the tab component. Now it works. Thanks